# Plotting fuzzy data with matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, plot, fuzzy

I don't know where to start, as I think it is a new approach for me. Using matplotlib with python, I would like to plot a set of fuzzy numbers (for instance a set of triangular or bell curve fuzzy numbers) as in the picture below:

[image: Example of image with several bell curves]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can plot the curves recurrently. My try at reproducing your example (including the superposition of labels 1 and 6):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# creating the figure and axis
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,constrained_layout=True)

# generic gaussian
y = np.linspace(-1,1,100)
x = np.exp(-5*y**2)

center_x = (0,2,4,1,3,0,5)
center_y = (6,2,3,4,5,6,7)

# loop for all the values
for i in range(len(center_x)):
    x_c, y_c = center_x[i], center_y[i]
    # plotting the several bells, relocated to (x_c, y_c)
    ax.plot(x + x_c,y + y_c,
            color='red',linewidth=2.0)
    ax.plot(x_c,y_c,
            'o',color='blue',markersize=3)
    # adding label
    ax.annotate(
        str(i+1),
        (x_c - 0.1,y_c), # slight shift in x
        horizontalalignment='right',
        verticalalignment='center',
        color='blue',
        )

ax.grid()
```

[image: Graph with several bell curves]

Every call to `ax.plot()` is adding points or curves (to be more precise, [Artists](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/artists.html)) to the same axis. The same for `ax.annotate()` to create the labels.